# Give an example of a sequence of functions $f_n$ which is uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$ and for which $\{f'_n(0)\}$ is unbounded.

Tags: examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

> Give an example of a sequence of functions $f_n$ which is uniformly convergent on $(-1,1)$ and for which $\{f'_n(0)\}$ is unbounded.

I thought of making the $f'_n$ part first.

If I take, $f'_n(x) = \frac{n}{1+n^2x}$ then $f'_n(0) = n$ which is unbounded.

But from here if I integrate it to make the $f_n(x)$ then it's becoming something like this :

$$f_n(x) = \frac{\ln(1+n^2x)}{n}$$, which not even defined on the $(-1,1)$.

Every time I'm fixing one part, problem keep coming on the other parts.

Can anyone please help me with this example?

**Edit :** I am thinking of another function I made in a similar manner.

I'm going directly to $f_n(x)$ part.

If $f_n(x) = \arctan nx$ then $f'_n(0) = n$, which is unbounded sequence.

But I'm having difficulty to figure out the uniform convergence of $f_n(x)$ here.

Comment: Your $f_n(x) = \arctan(nx)$ attempt is not uniformly convergent - the pointwise limit is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x > 0$, 0 for $x = 0$, and $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for $x < 0$ which is not continuous, whereas the individual $f_n$ are continuous.  However, you could revise the example to something like $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \arctan(n^2 x)$.  (On a similar note, the example that came to mind for me was: $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sin(n^2 x)$.)

Comment: Your example $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \sin(n^2x)$ is really amazing. It blowed my mind.

Comment: Can you shed some light on how to prove that $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \arctan(n^2 x)$ is uniformly convergent?

Comment: Well, to show $f_n$ uniformly converges to 0, it suffices to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \lVert f_n - 0 \rVert_\infty = 0$ where $\lVert f \rVert_\infty$ is notation for $\sup \{ |f(x)| \mid x \in \mathbb{R} \}$.  In the case of $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \arctan(n^2 x)$, what is $\lVert f_n \rVert_\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{(1-x)^{n^2}}n&\text{ if }x\in[0,1)\\\frac2n-\frac{(1+x)^{n^2}}n&\text{ if }x\in(-1,0).\end{cases}$$Then $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly to the null function, since$$(\forall x\in(-1,1))(\forall n\in\Bbb N):0<f_n(x)<\frac2n$$and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac2n=0$. Besides,$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):f_n'(0)=-n.$$To give you an idea, the graph of $f_3$ can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to show that this $f_n(x)$ will be uniformly convergent?

Comment: Also the sequence functions that I put in the edit $f_n(x)= \arctan nx$ has similar graph like yours. So will this one also work? Having the same problem to prove it's uniform convergence.

Comment: I've added to my answer an explanation of why $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges uniformly. And $(\arctan(nx))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ doesn't converge uniformly. It converges pointwise to$$x\mapsto\begin{cases}\frac\pi2&\text{ if }x>0\\0&\text{ if }x=0\\-\frac\pi2&\text{ if }x<0.\end{cases}$$However, $\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}\arctan(nx)\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ will work.

Comment: I understand now.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: $\left(\frac1{\sqrt n}\arctan(nx)\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is pointwise converging to the null function, am I correct?

Comment: It is *uniformly* convergent to the null function.

Comment: Yes yes I got that it is uniformly convergent, I was just asking about the limit function.

Answer (score 1):

A piecewise linear map defined by $f(-1) = -1$, $f(-1/n^2)=-1/n$, $f(1/n^2)=1/n$ and $f(1)=1$ would work.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: What do you want me to elaborate on? If you draw the graph of the map... This will be clear!

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand what values your sequence of functions taking in the rest of the points on $(-1,1)$ and also how $f'_n(0)$ is defined.